# Copy selected option value to another text box but just for some options

Tags: jquery

HTML excerpt

```
Selection:
<select name="no_exam" id="no_exam">
    <option value="" selected="selected">===select option===</option>
    <option value="A+">100-75</option>
    <option value="B+">50-74</option>
    <option value="C+">0-49</option>
    <option value="AB">AB</option>
    <option value="NE">NE</option>
    <option value="MC">MC</option>
</select>
</br>

Selected value:
<input type="text" name="std_marks" id="std_marks"/>
```

Javascript that is relevant to upper HTML

```
$("#no_exam").change(function() {
    var textval = $(":selected",this).val();
    $('input[name=std_marks]').val(textval);

    // if value is selected, text field is readonly
    result_form.std_marks.disabled=(!textval) ? false : true;
});
```

This code works ok... But I want to change it. My problem is that selection group has two categories... one is marks & other is absent..

```
--------------------------------------------------
* Marks category: 100-75,50-74,0-49
-----------------------------------------------------
* Absent category: AB,NE,MC
------------------------------------------------------
```

Here when I select an option its value gets copied to the input box.

How can I change this code to copy selected option's value when user selects one of the Absent category options but don't do anything when they select a Marks option?

Demo Link:- [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dontspeak/2zfdq/4)

Comment: why is demo html different than code in question? Makes it confusing as to what you want

Comment: @StevenHolzner: So you want the input box to be disabled when user selects something from the dropdown... And keep it enabled when nothing is selected from the dropdown? Where does parsing come into play (parsing as being a process of reading sub-data from selected option) **And** based on your poor English (I know you're doing your best) I think that you also want people to only be able to enter predefined values into textbox... In this case I would question having a textbox in the first place. Just use dropdown and remove textbox.

Comment: @StevenHolzner: Or you want to copy selected option's value to textbox **only when user selects Absent category** and don't do anything when user selects marks option?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik : no frnd I actually want to do is when I select Absent category value(AB,NE or MC) ,then It's value parse to  the Selected value text box only..I want to stop parsing when select Marks category value (A+,B+ or C) to the text box....That's my problem...[link](http://jsfiddle.net/2zfdq/3/)

Comment: @Robert Koritnik :that's right u have understood my problem...

Comment: I want to copy selected option's value to textbox only when user selects Absent category and don't do anything when user selects marks option....how to do that from this jQuery code

Comment: hel guys demo link updated :[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dontspeak/2zfdq/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed your HTML a bit to actually separate two option groups, and then also changed script to only copy value to textbox (and disable it) when an option from one of the groups is selected.

Here's the [changed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zfdq/6) that does the trick.

```
Selection :
<select name="myOption" id="myOption">
    <option value="" selected="selected">===select option===</option>
    <optgroup label="Marks" data-process="0">
        <option value="A+">100-75</option>
        <option value="B+">50-74</option>
        <option value="C+">0-49</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Absent" data-process="1">
        <option value="AB">AB</option>
        <option value="NE">NE</option>
        <option value="MC">MC</option>
    </optgroup>
</select></br>
Selected value :
<input type="text" name="student_mark"  id="student_mark"/>
```

And script

```
$("#myOption").change(function() {
    // get selected option
    var option = $(":selected", this);

    // get its value
    var value = option.val();

    // check if we need to copy value and disable input
    var process = option.parent().data("process") | 0;

    // get input box
    var input = $("#student_mark")[0];

    // set value and disable input
    input.value = value && process ? value : "";
    input.disabled = value && process && true || false;
});
```

Comment: Robert Koritnik : frnd little bit a problem..First  when I select Absent value then it's value parse to the text box. After that If I select  Marks option again then the text box value do not change to empty box..plzz slove this problem & give me the code...thanxx in advanced...